# Combining thread-last with loop in clojure

Tags: clojure

I write small card game and i want my code to be very explicit and therefore make it clear on a high level, that there are rounds to play. My first implementation was:

```
(defn play-game []
  (->
   (myio/initialize-cards-and-players)
   (shuffle-and-share-cards myio/myshuffle)
   ;(announce)
   (play-rounds)
  )
)
```

I want the play rounds to be more explicit and show, that it is a loop on top-level:

```
(defn play-game []


  (->>
   (myio/initialize-cards-and-players)
   (shuffle-and-share-cards myio/myshuffle)
   (announce)

   (loop [round 1]
     (play-round-with-game round)
     (if (<= round 4)
       (recur (+ round 1))
       )
     )
                                        ;   (play-round-with-game 2)
                                        ;   (play-round-with-game 3)
                                        ;   (play-round-with-game 4)


   )
  )
```

But i somehow cannot get the "game" object, that is returned by every function into the loop. Is there a good way to handle this with thread-last?

Or is there a way to use reduce instead of the loop?

Comment: Just extract the collection you need to use inside `loop` into its own binding within a `let` form. Or extract the collection preparation into its own function. The dumber the solution to this specific problem is, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eugene suggested, you want to keep it simple. The following is the structure I normally use

```
(defn play-game
  []
  (let [game-init (->>
                    (myio/initialize-cards-and-players)
                    (shuffle-and-share-cards myio/myshuffle)
                    (announce))]
    (loop [round 1
           game  game-init]
      (if (< 4 round)
        game ; return result
        (let [game-next (play-round-with-game game round)]
          (recur (inc round) game-next))))))
```

I like to use `let` forms to give each value an explicit name. It helps to avoid confusion, especially for new readers of the code. If the `(inc round)` was not so simple, I would also make an explicit `round-next` variable and use that in the `recur`.

Also, I like the return condition to be the first thing checked in each iteration of the loop.  This normally leaves the `recur` as the last statement in the loop.